# Cannot generate records using Choose(Denali) and Recursive CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to generate some records in a recursive CTE using the new choose function

```
    ;With Cte As
(
    Select 
        Id=1
        To = Cast ('India' as varchar(10))
    Union All
    Select 
        Id +1 
        ,To= Cast( Choose(ID,'India','Belgium') as varchar(10))     
    From Cte 
    Where Id < 10    
)

Select * from Cte
```

**Expected output**

```
Id  PlayerName                  BelongTo
1   Player1                     India
2   Player2                     Belgium
```

How can I do so using the Choose function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CHOOSE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213019%28SQL.110%29.aspx) is documented to return NULL:

> If the index value exceeds the bounds of the array of values

So you need to perform a modulo operation. The modulo operator in SQL is [%](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279%28SQL.110%29.aspx), so it would be:

```
Cast( Choose(((ID%4)+1),'India','Australia','England','Belgium') as varchar(100))
```

(I initially had a -1 from `ID`, but given that this statement is executing in a context where the `ID` value is from the previous row, that's already dealt with)